# How to grab the alphanumeric id at the end of a URL after the last forward slash in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to grab an alphanumeric id using a regex pattern to match the id at the end of the url after the last slash. I have a [**regex project**](https://regexr.com/6014o) here with tests to show what I am trying to achieve.

I want these kinds of values:

```
https://foo-bar/dashboard/?id=52dfa31d375aa456ff350d08
#                             ^^^
https://foo-bar/inbox/5d94b4a620c3d4db63a4609b
#                     ^^^
```

but not this value:

```
https://foo-bar/page/111618/export/
#                     ^^^
```

If anyone can help me out it would be greatly appreciated as I haven't had much luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like some kind of hash based on base64 or md5 (too long for md5), so it can contain a-f or 0-9. I added the `\s*`, because the third test contains space at the end. But if it was a mistake, just remove the `\s*` from the expression.

```
([a-fA-F0-9]+)\s*$
```

https://regexr.com/604cq

Or to be more exact:

```
[=\/]([a-fA-F0-9]+)\s*$
```

If it can contain more characters, you can extend it to:

```
[=\/]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*$
```

Comment: Hi @FlashThunder I think this is the best solution for my case & is more robust than the other solution! Thank you!

Comment: No worries - ++ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like `[^=\/]+$` ?

```js
const regex = /[^=\/]+$/gm;
const str = `https://foo-bar/dashboard/?id=52dfa31d375aa456ff350d08
https://foo-bar/inbox/5d94b4a620c3d4db63a4609b`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/yJp5G4/1/).